# Execution point between prepare-package and package in Maven build-process

Tags: maven-2, maven-3

The `package` phase of a project with packaging `war`, prepares an exploded-war in the `target` folder and packages this into the final `war`-file.

Is it possible to make some changes, editing files, removing files and so on, between `prepare-package` and `package` phases? I'm searching for an extension point (Maven `execution-phase`) where the resources are already copied and in the exploded-war structure.

1. [*maven phase*] Copy resources and explode to `target/{finalName}`.
2. [*custom*] Do some complex custom changes (e.g. implemented with `maven-antrun`).
3. [*maven phase*] Package the changed stuff into the final `war`.

I thought this could be possible between the phases `prepare-package` and `package`. Unfortunately after the `prepare-package` no exploded war is available to be changed and packaged later.

Can you give me a hint how to achieve this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maven war plugin can exclude files and filter them as well.  Perhaps your needs are more complex?

Comment: The needs are more complex, yes. I can't use this feature, it's not mighty enough.

Comment: You're going to have to explain a bit more what your [custom] changes are. Depending on what they are we might find different solutions to your problem.

Comment: @SaM: I have to extract a zip file with additional resources into this exploded war file, run a pre-compile phase (model-driven), delete some unused artifacts and at last package the whole thing into war.

Comment: hmm. It all sounds doable to me without going the way you considered. If you have to then you're probably not doing it the maven way and should reconsider your build a little… You might be making your build less maintainable. With even more details of what you're doing we could possibly help. What type of resources to you need to copy? What do you need to pre-compile? What does this code depend on? Why do you need to remove unused data? Sounds like it could be done in a separate module…

Comment: @SaM: It's very hard to move this to separate module. I found a way to work on the exploded war. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This configuration calls the `exploded` goal in the `prepare-package` phase. This gives you the chance to work on the exploded war directory in subsequent plugin definitions e.g. `maven-antrun`.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>prepare-war</id>
       <phase>prepare-package</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>exploded</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't dig deeper into that, I finally implemented my own war packager MOJO (wrote my own maven plugin) and rewrote the lifecycle for that.

Comment: How did you get maven-antrun to execute after the prepare-war task ? I'm using the exec plugin and it keeps executing before.

Comment: This works initially, but the changes I make in the exploded war directory are overwritten because maven-war-plugin runs a second time. It recreates the exploded war directory with the original files before packaging the war file. It there anyway to configure it so the second time it runs, maven-war-plugin will only package the exploded war into a war file?

Comment: @Nathan I found out what my problem is: Please note that maven-war-plugin 2.1.0+ copies resources twice which overrides replacements. See https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/wiki/UsageWithOtherPlugins for more information.

Comment: @ChristopherKlewes would you share your approach for you custom maven plugin. I need something very similar

Answer (score 1):

It sound to me like you should bind the antrun task to the prepare package phase, because at this point the resources have already been processed see [Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).